# Encrypt Decrypt 12 digit text by 32 characters key

Tags: c#, encryption, fixed

I am looking for a way to encrypt and decrypt 12 digits text by 32 characters long key. **The cipher must be of fixed length (32 or less). Is it possible?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is possible! But that needs some initial trial from you. What code have you written already?

Comment: What type of encryption do you want to use?  There are several different algorithms (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.aspx).  The cipher length is easily configurable for all of them.

Comment: Take a look at the following article - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845623/whats-the-best-way-to-encrypt-short-strings-in-net you also must realize that if the 12 characters is a password that simply is NOT long enough and should be padded and then encrypted.

Comment: @Ramhound: The plaintext has 12 characters. The key has 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. With a good block cipher (like [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)), you can choose between encrypting text as a block (the output will be a 32 character block) and you'll have 256 bit encryption or XORing the text with an encrypted nonce (the output will be a 12 byte ciphertext) and you'll have 96 bit encryption.

Just googling for AES and C# should come up with a ready-to-use implementation. Be sure to use a proper [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) (in some contexts also called [initialization vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector)).

To use a hash for your purposes (see comments on this answer), proceed as follows:

#### Hashing:

1. Compute `HASH = hash(FROM_DATE + TO_DATE + SECRET)`.
2. Output `FROM_DATE + TO_DATE + HASH`.

`+` denotes concenation and `SECRET` is only known to you.

If using only capitals and numbers, it should be **at least** 25 characters long.

#### Verification:

1. Split string into `FROM_DATE + TO_DATE` and `HASH`.
2. Verify that `HASH = hash(FROM_DATE + TO_DATE + SECRET)`

[SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) should work quite well for this.

Comment: Would it create cipher with length of exact 32 characters? Moreover, will all the characters be among capital letter or digit?

Comment: AES comes for 128, 192 and 256 bit keys. When encrypting the text (previously XORed with an initialization vector for security) with a 256 bit key, the ciphertext will have exactly 32 characters, (almost) randomly distributed among all 256 ASCII characters.

Comment: Well, I want cipher with only capital letters and digits (which I am going to use as product key). And I cannot use 1-way decryption using hash as I am attaching validation dates (from and to date) in plain text and need to decrypt cipher upon application startup. Any suggestion?

Comment: Capital letters and numbers are 36 characters. Cuts them down to 32, use 128 bits, and convert from 8 bit characters to base 32. It will work, but you could also use hash. I'll edit my answer to show you how.

Comment: Dennis, the way you suggested was exactly what I have implemented right now. But client don't want from and to date to be exposed (though it's ridiculous as validity should always be visible to user!). So, I cannot even implement that method :-(

Comment: Ridiculous indeed... Well, just use the 128 bit encryption and output the result as hexadecimal (A-Z and 0-9). Exactly 32 characters needed.